# How to get a new name for each element in a column based on other column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 30000 data. I would like to create a new column "Customer Name" based on "Customer ID" column.
example if the **Customer ID** is "100",anywhere in the data frame than the new column should show "**Customer1**" if Id is "200" then it should show "**Customer2**" I tried to do it with a for loop and function but in vain.

I have attached screenshot for the query that I have:

[image: AvailableData_and_OutputRequired]

Comment: So are there any values for CustomerID of "32500"? and do you then want to just drop the trailing two zeros? What about a number like "356000"? Just drop 2 zeros or all three?

Comment: yes , it has random values like  "32500"  repeating 10 times , what i require is to get a "Name " in all those 10 entries as "Customer[i]" , where i gets same value for those 10 customers , and if the customer id changes [i] will also change. Something like : if customerid[firstcell] == customerid[second cell] then CustomerName=CustomerName1,i=i+1, else( does not match then ) customername =customername2 ,till cell value changes, i hope i am able to clear my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your screenshot is representative of the real data you could try

```
data.frame$new.customer.id <- paste("Customer", CustomerID / 100, sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As a word of advice, can you in the future provide a representative example for your data, like:

```
 dput(yourData)
```

which produces something like:

```
 structure(list(Receipt_no = 111:116, Customer_ID = c(100L, 100L, 
 200L, 300L, 100L, 400L), Customer_Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Customer 1", "Customer 2", "Customer 3", 
 "Customer 4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Receipt_no",   "Customer_ID", 
 "Customer_Name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

You could similarly use mutate in dplyr.

```
library("dplyr")
tbl_df(yourData)%>%mutate(`Customer Name`=paste("Customer",as.numeric(unlist(yourData%>%select(2)))/100)
```

Comment: Sure, i will keep that in mind. I am new to R, so it seems from the answers that my question was bit vague. Thanks for the advice :)